Flutter: Android local notifications to launch app using Work Manager / Question about the right approach
I am working on a code that will check a list of items that are loaded from a json file, managed with Riverpod state management, and send local notifications. I read the official documentation on local notifications plugin. I wish to use notifications to inform about the items that are within due date in 3 days. App is working fine but the notification feature. I understand that I need to initialize on main and use the work manager to manage notifications while the app is in deep sleep/not running, but with below approach I am not quite seeing how that would work because the items list is not initialized with riverpod state management yet, but I don't know where to approach to this. Besides running the app gives below error:
main.dart:
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async {
    await NotificationService().checkDueDate();
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  NotificationService().initialize();
  Workmanager().initialize(callbackDispatcher);
  Workmanager().registerPeriodicTask(
    "dueDateChecker",
    "dueDateCheckerTask",
    frequency: const Duration(days: 1),
  );
  storage = Storage();
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
 }

NotificationService.dart:
class NotificationService {
  static final NotificationService _instance = NotificationService._internal();
  factory NotificationService() {
    return _instance;
  }
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  NotificationService._internal();
  Future<void> initialize() async {
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
    AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');

    const InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
    InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
    );
    //iOS: initializationSettingsDarwin);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: notificationTapForeground,
      onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: notificationTapBackground,
    );

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .getNotificationAppLaunchDetails()
        .then((NotificationAppLaunchDetails? details) {
      if (details != null && details.didNotificationLaunchApp) {
        print("tapped when app is not running");
        navigatorKey.currentState?.context.push("/inventory");
        // TODO: Handle notification that caused the app to launch
        // You can access details.notificationResponse.payload here
      }
    });
  }
    Future<void> _showNotification(List<Item> items) async {
      const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
      AndroidNotificationDetails('0', 'Impending Due Date',
          channelDescription: 'Impending Due Date Notification',
          actions: <AndroidNotificationAction>[
            AndroidNotificationAction('0', 'Go to Inventory'),
            AndroidNotificationAction('1', 'Close'),
          ],
          importance: Importance.max,
          priority: Priority.high,
          ticker: 'ticker');
      const NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
      NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);
      String dueItems = items.map((item) => item.name).join(', ');
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          0, 'Impending Due Date', 'Your $dueItems is due soon!',
          notificationDetails,
          payload: 'item x');
    }

    Future<void> notificationTapBackground(
        NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {
      switch (notificationResponse.actionId) {
        case '0':
          navigatorKey.currentState?.context.push("/inventory");
          print('Action 1 was pressed');
          break;
        case '1':
          print('Action 2 was pressed');
          break;
        default:
        // Handle the main notification tap (if the notification itself was tapped, not an action button)
        //print('Notification tapped, payload: ${notificationResponse.payload}');
      }
    }

    Future<void> notificationTapForeground(
        NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {
      switch (notificationResponse.actionId) {
        case '0':
          navigatorKey.currentState?.context.push("/inventory");
          print('Action 1 was pressed');
          break;
        case '1':
          print('Action 2 was pressed');
          break;
        default:
        // Handle the main notification tap (if the notification itself was tapped, not an action button)
        //print('Notification tapped, payload: ${notificationResponse.payload}');
      }
    }

  Future<void> checkDueDate() async {
    final currentItemList = ProviderContainer().read(jsonInventoryServiceNotifierProvider);
    late var dueDateList;
    currentItemList.when(
      data: (item) {
        dueDateList = item
            .where((element) =>
        element.dueDate != null &&
            element.calculateDueDate() <=
                3)
            .toList();
      },
      loading: () => print("loading.."),
      error: (e, st) => print("error.."),
    );
    _showNotification(dueDateList);
  }
}

Error on running the app:
 The backgroundHandler needs to be either a static function or a top level function to be accessible as a Flutter entry point.

